# Stack Exchange mobile app push notifications on ANDROID PIE 9 Nokia 6.1+

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

I have been a constant user of the Stack Exchange mobile app and on my previous mobile `Motorolla Droid Turbo 2` it worked fine, and I used to receive the push notifications for all the selected events like tag, message, reply, etc.

I recently bought `Nokia 6.1 +` with `Android 9` and since I installed the app I never received a single notification for the inbox or replies.

**Device Info**

```
App Version: 1.0.95
Device Manufacturer: HMD Global
Device Model: Nokia 6.1 Plus
OS Version: 9 (00WW_3_45B)
```

[image]

I checked the notifications checkbox in the settings menu several times, but it never a single time displayed the push notifications. Did anyone else experience a similar issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the extra battery limitations in Pie. Notifications work fine on my Note9 8.1, but not my OnePlus 6T 9.0. Since the app isn't being developed anymore I don't think this will be fixed.

Comment: Please add the device/app specific info to the post via "About - Submit a bug report" option of Android app.

Comment: @älёxölüt just added the info you asked for

Comment: @TheWanderer i tested it with disabling Adaptive battery Feature section in my Nokia 6.1+ but it reacts the same no change

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yeah it's not anything the OEMs add. I have Adaptive Battery off on my 6T too. Strangely, I just updated my Note 9 to Pie and I still got your notification.

Comment: @TheWanderer That's strange, it means that something to do with nokia then? any ideas

Comment: http://dontkillmyapp.com

Comment: Try following the ADB instructions for disabling the power management app.

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting , i just configured it and will wait to see if it makes it work or not, thanks for your reply @TheWanderer